# Can't send custom Slack Message with version 3 of Bot Connector

Tags: botframework

I have a bot that replies with a message consisting only of attachments. When it works on Slack, it uses Slack attachment formatting quite heavily, thus I have to use `ChannelData` property.

In version 1 of BotConnector, the code was like this

```
        var reply = message.CreateReplyMessage();
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var attachments = new List<object>(); //Slack-formatted attachments
        //filling attachments...
        reply.ChannelData = new {attachments};
```

and it worked. Now, in version 3 code has changed to

```
        var reply = activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var attachments = new List<object>(); //Slack-formatted attachments
        //filling attachments...
        reply.ChannelData = new {attachments};

        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

which, basically, boils down to using different method to create reply, and another one to send the reply back.

Now, the problem is, that I don't get the reply back to Slack. Diagnostics in AppInsight show me that somewhere in Connector something like this happens:

> Exception type: System.ArgumentNullException
>
> Failed method: SlackChannel.SlackMapper+d__5.MoveNext
>
> Exception Message: value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
>
> ChannelData: {}
>
> message: Invalid ChannelData

Please note that `ChannelData` in this diagnostics seems to be empty. So what I gather from all this is that something has changed in the way BotConnector processes `ChannelData`. How can I find out what exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is inside the `ConnectorClient` client, which strips `channelData`. The reason for that lies in [its serialization settings](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/c4dbb7183cc1c23837b6d6c8bc03fe8c54ba1f55/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/ConnectorAPI/ConnectorClient.cs#L131) which use `ReadOnlyJsonContractResolver`, which skips all read-only properties - and of course all the properties in anonymous class are read-only.

Knowing that, the solution is quite simple:

`reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new {attachments});`

Note the explicit use of `JObject` instead of anonymous class.

Comment: added a Gist for help https://gist.github.com/phaniav/cf03f8f62ee7c6dc891486d8df893794